# Is there a class for lazily computed values somewhere in the popular/standard Java libraries?

Tags: java

I'm wondering whether there is a "standard" class somewhere (JDK, Guava, Apache *), that would help with the lazy initialization/computation pattern?

I'm thinking about something like this (let's ignore synchronization for now):

```
abstract class Lazy<T> {
  T instance = null;
  protected T compute();
  final T get() {
    if (instance == null) instance = compute();
    return instance;
  }
}

//...

Lazy<Foo> foo = new Lazy<Foo> {
  protected Foo compute() { return Foo.expensivePart(); }
}

//...

Bar bar = foo.get().getBar();
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, then [Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/features/GetterLazy.html) will do the job with a single annotation `@Getter(lazy=true)`.

(Lombok also offers some further very useful annotations, such as `@Delegate, @EqualsAndHashCode, @Synchronized`).

Comment: Thanks, this is neat :) Since it is concise, automatic and uses the double-check idiom, I guess Effective Java Item 71, 
use lazy initialization judiciously, no longer applies.

Comment: I wonder which of Lombok's features (http://projectlombok.org/features/index.html) are outdated because of Java 7 (e.g. val due to the diamond operator).

Comment: @DaveBall I do not know and I do not like all features of Lombok. But some of them are very very neat. I found it in a suggestion here on StackOverflow a few weeks ago. It's nice to play with but imo the project does not look mature enough for use in production yet. But that's just my opinion and maybe it helps here to know that there is something out there doing this lazy loading for you. Maybe Michael takes it and writes something similar on his own or whatever ...

Comment: @DaveBall Thanks for the edit. :) These are in fact some of the very neat features Lombok has. But I do not like `@SneakyThrows`, `val` and `@Log`, for example. In my opinion these 3 do more harm than they help.